# Galaxybase graph database server prompt "Message hasn't started"

Tags: graph-databases

I'm experiencing an issue while using the Galaxybase graph database. The error message I encounter is "Message hasn't started."

```
import com.galaxybase.driver.GraphDatabase;
import com.galaxybase.driver.GraphSession;

public class GraphDBExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            GraphDatabase graphDB = new GraphDatabase("127.0.0.1"); // Connect to the local Galaxybase graph database
            GraphSession session = graphDB.createSession();

            // Execute query or operation statements
            session.execute("MATCH (n:Node) RETURN n");

            // Prematurely closing the connection leads to server-side exception
            session.close();

            graphDB.close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Handle exceptions
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```